# Изменение уровня масштабирования google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Как возможно приблизить карту сразу по местности, а именно, если как на примере маркеры находятся в одном городе, то сразу открывать приближенную карту этого города.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Маркеры добавляю пока следующим образом:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
    createMapView();
}


private void createMapView() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
            .title("Marker"));


    builder.include(marker.getPosition()); 

    LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

    int padding = 50; 
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
    map.moveCamera(cu);
}
```

P.S. наверное не самое удачное решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо воспользоваться [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds)

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Marker"));

builder.include(marker.getPosition()); //засунуть все маркеры

LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

int padding = 50; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
map.moveCamera(cu);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы Вы пожалуйста немного пояснить как именно я могу "засунуть все маркеры" в marker.getPosition, если я сейчас добавляю маркеры как показано в вопросе(обновил вопрос).

Comment: @Morozov, обновил ответ

Comment: Маркер "уплыл" в море) теперь даже зумом не могу приблизить территорию или же куда то передвигаться по карте.

Comment: @Morozov, походу вы сделали, что то не так

Comment: скорей всего, взгляните пожалуйста еще раз на реализацию.

Comment: @Morozov,  все верно, координаты 0, 0 находятся в атлантическом океане.